# how to avoid assignment If one value is set on django model field?

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have a product model with 2 foreign keys to models percentDiscount and cashDiscount, I want to apply just one of these discounts on my unit price. So I defined a final_price property to get the final_price of the item. but I want to apply one of these discounts on items at the moment. There are 2 ways, 1) when one of the discounts is set, do not let another be set and set it as none. 2) do something in the final price to set just one of these discounts.
Below is my code, I will be happy if you help me to make the best decision.

```
class Product(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'محصول'
        verbose_name_plural = 'محصولات'
        ordering = ('created_at',)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    category = models.ForeignKey('product.Category', on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='products')
    brand = models.ForeignKey('product.Brand', on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='products')
    # labels such as bestseller, new, not available, etc ...
    label = models.CharField(choices=LABEL, max_length=1)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='product/static/product/images/', null=True, blank=True)
    description = models.TextField(max_length=1000, null=True, blank=True)
    is_original = models.BooleanField()
    inventory = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, null=True, blank=True)
    unit_price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=8, decimal_places=2)
    number_sold = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    # discount code for this book
    cash_code = models.ForeignKey('cart.CashDiscount', null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True,
                                  related_name='related_products')
    percentage_code = models.ForeignKey('cart.PercentageDiscount', null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE,
                                        related_name='related_products', blank=True)
    # for food and health products:
    expiration_date = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)
    slug = AutoSlugField(populate_from=['name', 'brand'], allow_unicode=True, unique=True)`

    @property
    def final_price(self):
        if self.get_sale():
            return self.get_sale()
        else:
            return self.unit_price

    def get_sale(self):
        if self.cash_code:
            return self.unit_price - self.cash_code.amount
        elif self.percentage_code:
            return self.unit_price - ((self.percentage_code.percentage * self.unit_price) // 100)
        else:
            return None
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if self.cash_code:
            self.percentage_code = None
        elif self.percentage_code:
            self.cash_code = None
        else:
            self.percentage_code = None
            self.cash_code = None
        super(Product, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: I think the way you processed it in `get_sale` is enough, so it's still fine to have both fields present (no need to set the other to `None`). Maybe just change the return of `final_price()` to just: `return self.get_sale() or self.unit_price` so you don't calculate `get_sale()` twice.

Comment: I have to set one of them none if another is been set, so because of that i override the save method, both are needed. but not gonna use them at the same time.